# jersey 2.7 issue while running it on apache tomcat 7.0

Tags: java, tomcat, jersey-2.0

I am creating a jersey application using apache tomcat 7.0 and eclipse. 
I have created a dynamic web project in eclipse and have defined a resource file as:-

```
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

// Plain old Java Object it does not extend as class or implements 
// an interface

// The class registers its methods for the HTTP GET request using the @GET annotation. 
// Using the @Produces annotation, it defines that it can deliver several MIME types,
// text, XML and HTML. 

// The browser requests per default the HTML MIME type.

//Sets the path to base URL + /hello
@Path("/hello")
public class Hello {

  // This method is called if TEXT_PLAIN is request
  @GET
  @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
  public String sayPlainTextHello() {
    return "Hello Jersey";
  }

  // This method is called if XML is request
  @GET
  @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_XML)
  public String sayXMLHello() {
    return "<?xml version=\"1.0\"?>" + "<hello> Hello Jersey" + "</hello>";
  }

  // This method is called if HTML is request
  @GET
  @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
  public String sayHtmlHello() {
    return "<html> " + "<title>" + "Hello Jersey" + "</title>"
        + "<body><h1>" + "Hello Jersey" + "</body></h1>" + "</html> ";
  }

}
```

web.xml file is also created as below-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
  <display-name>de.vogella.jersey.first</display-name>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
      <param-value>de.vogella.jersey.first</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Following jar files have been added to lib folder in web-inf and are also coming in directory structure in web-apps after war file is deployed.

The problem which is coming as soon as i start tomcat and war file is deployed following error is displayed:

> org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component
>   [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/de.vogella.jersey.first]]
>           at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:634)
>           at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:1074)
>           at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1858)
>           at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
>           at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
>           at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724) Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   jersey/repackaged/com/google/common/base/Function
>           at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.ServiceFinder.(ServiceFinder.java:165)
>           at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.internal.ServletContainerProviderFactory.getAllServletContainerProviders(ServletContainerProviderFactory.java:66)
>           at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.init.JerseyServletContainerInitializer.onStartup(JerseyServletContainerInitializer.java:132)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5444)
>           at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
>           ... 11 more Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: jersey.repackaged.com.google.common.base.Function
>           at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1702)
>           at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1547)
>           ... 16 more

I have added following jars to lib folder:

```
**/de.vogella.jersey.first/WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/guava-16.0.1.jar
/de.vogella.jersey.first/WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/jersey-client.jar
/de.vogella.jersey.first/WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/jersey-common.jar
/de.vogella.jersey.first/WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/jersey-container-servlet-core.jar
/de.vogella.jersey.first/WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/jersey-container-servlet.jar
/de.vogella.jersey.first/WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/jersey-server.jar**
```

But still this error is coming, please tell me where i am going wrong.

Answer (score 45):

At last solved. Please check below jar files. It is disgusting to use this number of jar files to implement REST services. May be restlet or easy rest is better than jersey.

```
hk2-api-2.2.0.jar
hk2-locator-2.2.0.jar
hk2-utils-2.2.0.jar
javassist-3.18.1-GA.jar
javax.annotation-api-1.2.jar
javax.inject-2.2.0.jar
javax.ws.rs-api-2.0.jar
jersey-client.jar
jersey-common.jar
jersey-container-servlet.jar
jersey-container-servlet-core.jar
jersey-guava-2.8.jar
jersey-server.jar,
validation-api-1.1.0.Final.jar
```

Hope someone may find this useful. The above is known working with jersey version 2.8

Comment: Its an awful lot. But this helped.Found this after 2 days of head banging. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 5):

I believe you are missing Google guava dependency jars missing. Try to download and add them to your classpath.

Comment: I have added them also:

/de.vogella.jersey.first/WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/guava-16.0.1.jar

are there any other i need to add

Answer (score 1):

Was able to get the basic REST webservice working for Jersey 2.8.Do let me know if there is a better way to do this.

pom.xml:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.8</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId>
        <version>2.8</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

web.xml:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>jersey-servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
        org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer
    </servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>jersey.config.servlet.provider.webapp</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>jersey-servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Greeting.java:

```
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

@Path("greeting")
public class Greeting {
@GET
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
public String greeting(){
    return "Welcome!!";
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the following jar files to your web-inf/lib folder, also you need to configure build path -- Right click your project--Build path -- configure build path -- libraries -- add external jars (add all the below jar files). And restart server

[image: JerseyLibs]

Answer (score 0):

jersey-guava-2.x.jar is the jar you may be missing on your runtime setup - you may want to package all the extension jars as found under jaxrs-ri/ext from the Jersey JAX-RS 2.0 RI bundle - see https://jersey.java.net/download.html